# Dynatree select first node as default selected node.

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am creating dynatree. I want to set first node of dynatree to be selected on opening dynatree. I set select= tree in json for first element. but it does't work.
I want to skip adding select property in json. It is better to get something on dynatree() function.

"[{"Id":16,"ParentId":0,"Parent":null,"title":"X","key":"16","isFolder":true,"select":true,"children":[{"Id":17,"ParentId":16,"Parent":null,"title":"X1,"key":"17","isFolder":true,"select":false,"children":[{"Id":35,"ParentId":17,"Parent":null,"title":"X2","key":"35","isFolder":true,"select":false,"children":[]}]}]}]"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing 'select' with 'activate'?
Try

```
{... "activate": true, ...
```

instead.
You can also call node.activate() for a node in the onPostInit event.

Comment: But this change is in json. i want something dynatree() function. Now i am searching first node in PostInit method and setting that node to be active.

Comment: This is what I was trying to suggest by "You can also call node.activate() for a node in the onPostInit event" :)

Comment: That is last option. I was looking any direct method in dynatree which will do this 2 operation directly .